# Azure Max DB Connections on Release to Prod

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

When we release our Sitecore site to Production, the release takes 7 to 8 mins, and when it seems to be back up, we are getting the warning:

> The request limit for the database is 90 and has been reached.

The site is then unavailable for an extended period (at least 40 mins)

We are trying to reason why a release could cause an excessive number of connections (we can see a spike in successful connections in Azure analytics). My gut is telling me that it may be due to the 7 to 8 minute downtime when the site is unavailable. It seems the connections are 'backed up' somehow but what I don't understand is why there are database connections if the site is unavailable. Any ideas?